# Allow nulls in Integer column SQLite Android Room

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-room

I am attempting to add a new column to my database using

```
static final Migration MIGRATION_16_17 = new Migration(16,17) {
        @Override
        public void migrate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {

            database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE `myTable` ADD COLUMN newColumn INTEGER");

        }
    };
```

However it is giving me the error:

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Migration didn't properly handle: Clothes(com.dayaramo.wearyourcloset.Objects.ClothingItem).

The issue is that it's expecting notNull=true even though I want to allow nulls in this column.

My question is can an Integer column have nulls and if so how do I set notNull=false?

My entity class

```
 @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private long id;
    private String item;
    private int itemProductNum;
    private int newColumn;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `int` can never be null, there is no way for room to map a database row, where `newColumn` is actually null, to an `int`.

`Integer` however can be null, since it is an `int` wrapped into an object, so try this instead:

```java
private Integer newColumn;
```

Comment: I see. When I first create the table I had an Integer column that I set as an int in my entity class. Did it work because there weren't any entries in the table?

Comment: I assume it works because room generated a table where that column is marked as "NOT NULL".

Comment: Oh yes I just checked and it is. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

if you are using kotlin you can use

@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
private long id
private String item?
private Int itemProductNum
private Int newColumn = 0

by giving a default value